# Sum of only specific columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas, dataframe

Consider I have a dataframe with few columns

[image: before operation]

and a list ['salary','gross exp']

Now I want to perform sum of the column operation only on the columns from the list on the dataframe and save that to the dataframe

To put this in prespective, the list of columns ['salary','gross exp'] are money related and it makes sense to perform  sum on these columns and not touch any of the other columns

[image: after operation]

P.S: I have several Excel workbooks to work on and each consists of few tens of sheets, so doing it manually is out of options

Also macro code for excel works fine if that's possible

TIA

Comment: you mean `df[list].sum()`?

Comment: Next time, to get a better chance of getting a reply, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the dataframes (instead of pictures). I have built one in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Working with the following example:

```py
import pandas as pd

list_ = ['sallary', 'gross exp']
d = {'sallary': [1,2,3], 'gross exp': [2,2,2], 'another column': [10,10,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

|  | sallary | gross exp | another column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 10 |

You can then add a new empty row, and insert the sum of the columns that you have from the list in that same row:

```py
df = df.append(pd.Series(dtype = float), ignore_index=True)
df.loc[df.index[-1],list_] = df[list_].sum()
df
```

|  | sallary | gross exp | another column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 10.0 |
| 1 | 2.0 | 2.0 | 10.0 |
| 2 | 3.0 | 2.0 | 10.0 |
| 3 | 6.0 | 6.0 | NaN |